# r frequency counts on overlayed histogram and density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

I am interested in adding frequency count on a histogram overlayed by density plot. [This question is similar to a question already posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404531/r-ggplot2-adding-count-labels-to-histogram-with-density-overlay) by other user. I tried the solution provided for that question and it did not work.

This is my test dataset

```
df <- data.frame(cond = factor( rep(c("A","B"), each=200)), 
                 rating = c(rnorm(200), rnorm(200, mean=.8)))
```

This will plot a histogram with counts

`ggplot(df, aes(x=rating)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, colour="black", fill="white")`

This will plot a density plot like this

`ggplot(df, aes(x=rating)) + geom_density()`

I try to combine the two,

`ggplot(df, aes(x=rating)) + 
       geom_histogram(aes(y=..count..),  binwidth=.5, colour="black", fill="white") +
       geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666")`

The overlaid density plot is gone.

I tried this approach

`ggplot(df, aes(x=rating)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, colour="black", fill="white") +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count.., ,binwidth=0.5,label=..count..), geom="text", vjust=-.5) + 
       geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666")`

This is almost okay but does not show the density plot and overwites my bindwidth value (head scratcher).

How do I keep the histograms with counts and show the overlaid density plot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will resolve your problem. The issue is related to the binwidth You need to adjust the y values for the density plot by the count and the bin width, as density always = 1.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(cond = factor( rep(c("A","B"), each=200)), 
                 rating = c(rnorm(200), rnorm(200, mean=.8)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=rating)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), binwidth = 0.5, colour = "black", fill="white") +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count.., binwidth = 0.5,label=..count..), geom="text", vjust=-.5) + 
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count.. * 0.5), alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666")


# This is more elegant: using the built-in computed variables for the geom_ functions


ggplot(df, aes(x = rating)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..ncount..), binwidth = 0.5, colour = "black", fill="white") +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..ncount.., binwidth = 0.5,label=..count..), geom="text", vjust=-.5) + 
  geom_density(aes(y = ..scaled..), alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666")
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter. i will change the binwidth value and tweak the plot to fit my data.

Comment: Up to you what you do ... but the second solution is by far the best as it will be independnent of the binwidth.